# why listbox always selecting first item true

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In My Application my first ListBox is populating on selected index of Dropdown and then According to Multiple Selected Item in my First Listbox i am filling SecondList box.

The Problem is That Second Listbox always taking first item in FirstList Box even it is not selected,

to populate the first list box my code is

```
 protected void ddlSkillType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TblSkillType> lstSkillType = ServiceAccess.GetProxy().GetSkillType();
        List<TblSkill> lstSkill = ServiceAccess.GetProxy().GetAllSkill();
        List<TblSkillDetail> lstSkillDetails = ServiceAccess.GetProxy().GetAllSkillDtls();
        var skill = (from a in lstSkillType
                     from b in lstSkill
                     from c in lstSkillDetails
                     where a.SkillTypeId == Convert.ToInt32(ddlSkillType.SelectedValue) && a.SkillTypeId == b.SkillTypeId && b.SkillId == c.SkillId
                     select new { b.SkillId, c.SkillName }).ToList();
        lstboxSkill.DataSource = skill;
        lstboxSkill.DataTextField = "SkillName";
        lstboxSkill.DataValueField = "SkillId";
        lstboxSkill.DataBind();
    }
```

and for filling second listbox my code is

```
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstboxSkill.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstboxSkill.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(lstboxSkill.Items[i]);
            }

        }
```

}

i am checking it using break point and i found Second ListBox Always taking fistitem of firstList box even it is not selected.
that is forloop is always true infirst iteration and false after it even first item in lstboxSkill is not select 
and after multiple selecting in first listbox,second listbox fills with multiple fistitem of first listbox 
i don't know what is the problem.
Kindly help me to fix it.

Thanks In advance...!!

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accpeted if it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling `listbox` just write this line

```
lstBBoxSkill2.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

or

```
lstBBoxSkill2.ClearSelected();
```